# Android rooted phone screenshots

Tags: android

I'd like to take screenshots on my android phone.  I'm an app developer and have a pretty good understanding of the regular API, and I know this steps out of the "regular" thing quite a bit.

I would have root access.

I've seen a few apps that do this.  I'm just wondering how one goes about doing it.  Anybody know the general direction I should be looking in?

Comment: I meant more like how do I do this in code, for an app I'm writing.  This will not be something deployed to the store specifically for capturing screenshots.  its sort of part of a broader app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at framebuffer.c in the adb (phone side) sources, which appears to be what the DDMS screenshot capability uses.  You need to be uid root or gid graphics due to the permissions on the framebuffer device - presumably the adbd is the later.

It is in `/platform/system/core`:

Direct link to the file:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/gingerbread-release/adb/framebuffer_service.c

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  I'll take a look.

Comment: This is an old answer that was accurate for the context of the question it responded to, but there have been many changes to how ADB screenshots work in the years since.

Answer (score 0):

drocap2 is usually what I have seen used (free app found in market). Alternatively, if you would like to take a screenshot from your PC, I know Motodev Studio has a plugin for this in their IDE (not sure if it is available for other eclipse based IDEs).

Comment: I mean more like how would I do it in an app I'm writing, but this is definitely a good place to start looking around.  At the end of the day, there's a good chance I'm just going to hire somebody to do that part of the app.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is get look in to the `/system/bin/screencap`.
Since you have root access you can easily get rid of it without the overhead of reading and writing buffer.